# Apache2 not responding on Amazon EC2

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-ec2, httpd

It is my first time to use Amazon EC2 linux micro instance with OS Ubuntu 12.04

[inside the box]

I noticed it did not have Apache installed by default, so I did `sudo apt-get install apache2`. After installation there is the `/var/www` directory, and I verified the Apache 2 daemon is running

When I did `curl http://localhost:80` it successfully returned content in `/var/www/index.html`.

[outside the box]

When I type the public DNS name into browser, it gets a page not found error. **How can I get the web page to load when the DNS name is entered instead?**

Comment: Did you open port 80 on the __AWS__ firewall?

Comment: great, it works!! thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

1) VPC. Check inbound and outbound rules.
2) Subnet. Check that you have IGW attached.
3) Instance security groups. Check that port 80 is allowed.